# How can a README.md file be included in a PyPI module package using setup.py?

Tags: setup.py, pypi, readme

I want to include a `README.md` file with my module package for PyPI such that it can be read by a function in my `setup.py`. However, it is not obvious to me how to get `setup.py` and related infrastructure to actually include the `README.md` file.

I have included a `MANIFEST.in` file in my package that itself lists `README.md` and I have set the `setuptools.setup` argument `include_package_data` to `True` but this has not worked.

`manifest.in`:

```
junkmodule.py
junkmodule_script.py
LICENSE
MANIFEST.in
README.md
setup.py
```

`setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import pypandoc
import setuptools

def main():

    setuptools.setup(
        name                 = "junkmodule",
        version              = "2017.01.13.1416",
        description          = "junk testing module",
        long_description     = pypandoc.convert("README.md", "rst"),
        url                  = "https://github.com/user/junkmodule",
        author               = "LRH",
        author_email         = "lhr@psern.ch",
        license              = "GPLv3",
        include_package_data = True,
        py_modules           = [
                               "junkmodule"
                               ],
        install_requires     = [
                               "numpy"
                               ],
        scripts              = [
                               "junkmodule_script.py"
                               ],
        entry_points         = """
            [console_scripts]
            junkmodule = junkmodule:junkmodule
        """
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The commands I use to register and upload the module to PyPI are as follows:

```
python setup.py register -r https://pypi.python.org/pypi
python setup.py sdist upload -r https://pypi.python.org/pypi
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in my modules, try:

```
import pypandoc


try:
    description=pypandoc.convert('README.md', 'rst')
except (IOError, ImportError):
    description=open('README.md').read()
```